# All Files Access Permission Policy: Not a core feature App Rejected by Playstore

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-fileprovider

The story starts when my app get rejected from Play Store. I have a feature that user needs to take picture and upload to Server. So I have to take picture and save it somewhere in the storage area.

So I have these permissions in android manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.test.fileupload.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <!-- ressource file to create -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
```

For Android APi 30 + , there is a need to request MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE otherwise, it crashes .

```
 <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:minSdkVersion="30" /
```

> 

I save images to externalStorage.

```
   val storageDir: File? = File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"/myimages")
```

Even I save photos in app's internal storage , MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is required for API 30+. Otherwise it crashes.

Update -> I change it to

with

```
 val storageDir: File? = File( context?.filesDir.toString() +"/my_images")
```

And some says we are supposed to use MediaStore . And I have tried

```
val mimeType = "image/*"
                val values = ContentValues().apply {
                    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, getNewFileName())
                    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, mimeType)
                    put(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,
                        relativeLocation
                    )
                }
val imageUri =
                        context.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL), values)
                    if (imageUri != null) {
                        currentPhotoPath = imageUri.toString()
                        shareUri = imageUri
                    }
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)
```

The problem only happens when I try to convert imageUri to File .
imageUri from mediastore doesn't provide full path . I need actual file path so that I can upload to server.

Which library  should I use to save image so that my app got approved by Google Playstore? It has been long week .Any comment/ solution is really appreciated .

Comment: "Even I save photos in app's internal storage , MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is required for API 30+. Otherwise it crashes." -- consider modifying your question to provide the stack trace of the crash and the code associated with that stack trace. `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is not needed for `getFilesDir()` on `Context` or other places on internal storage. "I save images to externalStorage" -- you do not have write access to the root of external storage.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes you are right it was my fault. I fixed it already. And do you thinks my app gonna  get approved if I use getFilesDir  (Internal Storage)?. Should I use MediaStore ? I try MediaStore and  I do not get full file path if I use MediaStore. I need filepath to upload to our server

Comment: "And do you thinks my app gonna get approved if I use getFilesDir (Internal Storage)?." -- they are unlikely to block you for `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` if you are not using `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. "I need filepath to upload to our server" -- there certainly are options for uploading content to servers without a filesystem path.